# to search the data from database

Tags: sql

I want to search the data from database from table. Throw one input box I give nput (like mobile, name, id, anything I want ) and search and give out put

Comment: You need to write code for this. Did you write? What issue you are facing in that ?

Comment: Did you write a SELECT query which did not work? Can you share what you have tried

Comment: $qry1='SELECT * FROM gym_member WHERE (`name` LIKE `%".$datasearch."%`) OR (`mobile` LIKE `%".$datasearch."%`))' ;

Comment: i want to search from one input box (if i input id or mobile or email) on it then it fetch from it and give me result of one person full details

Answer (score -1):

Logic is something like that

```
SELECT * FROM table  WHERE (condition)
```

For your case, you may as well use

```
SELECT 'mobile','name','id', '...any from its table...'   FROM table_name
```

Comment: i want to search from one input box (if i input id or mobile or email) on it then it fetch from it and give me result of one person full details

Comment: SELECT * FROM table_name  WHERE name='person_name' OR email='email' OR mobile='mobile'        Whatever you've  one attribut of person, You can use it in WHERE "condition"